# css3/Jquery animation/transition/: How to make image move vertically and back?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to do this effect in my image (button)

http://osc4.template-help.com/wt_32608/index.html#
I want to make this animation whatever the method CSS3, HTML5 canvas , JS

If I will use Hover property , how can I make the image slide and back when roolout

Comment: use `top` [in css] its more reliable and supported by all browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make a < div > that will contain the animation.

```
<div id="image_holder"></div>
```

Then, place the < img > inside.

```
<div id="image_holder_1" class="image_holder">
    <img id="image_1" class="image" ..... />
</div>
```

Next, add some CSS styling to the < div > like so:

```
.image_holder {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

And also some CSS to the < img >:

```
.image {
    position: relative;
}
```

Now, animate the image with jQuery. Specifically, you will be animating the "top" CSS attribute for the image:

```
$('#image_holder_1').hover( function() {
    $('#image_1').animate({
        top: '-' + $(this).height() + 'px'
    });
}, function() {
    $('#image_1').animate({
        top: '0px'
    });
});
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/trusktr/7hTDu/

Alternatively, you can do it with CSS3 animations. Do a search for "CSS3 transitions" on google: http://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=CSS3+transitions

Answer (score 0):

something like this.

```
$(".items").each(function() {
$(this).mouseover(function(){
$(this).find(".inner").slideDown();
});
$(this).mouseout(function(){
$(this).find("inner").slideUp();
});
});
```

but it would be better if you give us some code of your html struct, and something aboute your idea.

Comment: The idea is  the same in the example 
http://osc4.template-help.com/wt_32608/index.html#
and I'll put my html :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to position the images absolutely and then manipulate the `top`, something like this:

```
<img id="myimage" style="position: absolute" src="whatever"/>

<script>

$('#myimage').animate({top: '<whatever>px' },someDuration);

</script>
```

Read the jQuery animate docs here: http://www.google.dk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jquery+animate

It should not be that hard to figure out :)

Comment: Still new in jQuery  :)
I'll try now .

Answer (score 0):

If just an animated background to a button you want, why not use `background-image` and animate the `background-position` with jQuery?